# Query to list every line item but only list total once

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a sales report that pulls data from multiple tables and my query shows correct data except orders that have multiple line items, i.e., the Total from the Orders table is listed on every line item row.

How can we list the Order Total only once on the row that has the smallest line item ID (for that order) but still list every line item row?  Thanks!

Data Structure:

Orders Table:

- Order_ID
- Total

Line Items Table:

- ID
- Order_ID
- Line_Item_Price
- Line_Item_Qty

Result should be:

```
  Order_ID   Total   Line_Item_Price   Line_item_Qty   Line_Item_ID  
 ---------- ------- ----------------- --------------- -------------- 
     10001     200               100               2          32001  
     10002     150               150               1          32002  
     10003     210                55               1          32003  
     10003                        30               2          32004  
     10003                        95               1          32005  
     10004     125               125               1          32006
```

Comment: The query works great on Postgresql but when we use it on another platform that uses SPARQL (docs.data.world/documentation/sql/concepts/basic/intro.html) they rejected the Window functions. Is there another way to get the results? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done in the application not in SQL.

But you *can* do that using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
select o.order_id, 
       case row_number() over (partition by o.order_id order by line_item_id)
         when 1 then o.total
       end as total, 
       li.line_item_price,
       li.line_item_qty,
       li.line_item_id
from orders o 
  join line_item li on o.order_id = li.order_id
order by o.order_id, li.line_item_id;
```

`row_number()` assigns a unique row number for each line item for every order. When the number is `1` the total is displayed, otherwise it's not.

In a relational database there is no such thing as "the first row" unless you specify an `order by` - in this case the "first row" is the line item with the smallest `line_item_id`

Online example: http://rextester.com/TQOIX50171

---

Unrelated, but: storing the total in the `orders` table is not a terribly good idea. In a normalized design you shouldn't store information that can easily be derived from existing data.

Comment: I ran the query but got this error: "column line_item_id does not exist." Any ideas?  Good point about not storing data that can be derived from existing data but the tables are from an external source that we don't have control of.  The Orders table also has fields like Subtotal, tax, shipping, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: @LeoJones: then apparently - contrary to your example - your table doesn't have a column named `line_item_id`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  sorry it was my typo mistake. Your query works beautifully!  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I've accepted your answer. I'm learning the ins and outs of SO as well. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, the query works great on Postgresql but when we use it on another platform that uses SPARQL (https://docs.data.world/documentation/sql/concepts/basic/intro.html) they rejected the Window functions.  Is there another way to get the results?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What this does is get the orders with their items and ranks them. So that the smallest item_id is rank 1 for that order, and the latest is the last rank.

ROW_NUMBER() is the function that gives the index of the rows in the output of the query (row 1 = 1, row 2 = 2). Then we can combine this with OVER (PARTITION BY), which means get the row numbers within a certain window, a partition. In this case we want to number the rows for the windows of Order_IDs. We use ORDER BY alongside to say how we order the rows within the window

When we have this table, we can then write a query on it to show the total only on the rows where the item_rank = 1

```
WITH rank_items_for_orders AS (
   SELECT
          Order_ID,
          Line_Item_Price,
          Line_Item_Qty,
          Line_Item_ID,
          Total,
          ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY Order_ID, ORDER BY Line_Item_ID ASC) 
       AS order_the_items_IDs
     FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN line_items li ON o.order_id = li.order_id
 ORDER BY Order_ID ASC)

SELECT
       Order_ID,
       Line_Item_Price,
       Line_Item_Qty,
       Line_Item_ID,
      CASE WHEN order_the_items_IDs = 1 
      THEN Total ELSE NULL END 
        AS Total
FROM
rank_items_for_orders
```

Comment: How are the two tables joined to be able to use both Order_ID and Line_item_id in the window function as there is only one FROM Table statement and no joins?  Thanks!

Comment: @LeoJones Please see the updated left Join (I assumed you already had the data in a single table, sorry about that)